# find parent array of numpy slice array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Is it possible to find the parent array of a slice ie. the array that the slice is taken from? I would like to do this so I can add functionality to matplotlib plots which allows you to change which slice of an array you are viewing interactively in a plot. For instance, if I do this

```
plt.pcolormesh(myArray[0,:,:])
```

I would like to be able to run some code to change the plot to

```
plt.pcolormesh(myArray[1,:,:])
```

but to do that I need to know that myArray[0,:,:] is a slice of myArray.

Thanks
Niall

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With simple slices, you can look at the `base` attribute:

```
a = np.arange(50)
b = a[10:20]
print (b.base is a)
```

However, I don't believe that this is guaranteed to work in *all* circumstances...(depending on contiguousness of `a`, etc.)

Comment: Basically, there is another problem with this. It could be that `b.base is a.base` and not `b.base is a` also. There is `np.may_share_memory`, which will tell you that the two must have some common base, but there is no way to find out if one is a slice of the other, since two arrays may be incompatible slices of the same array.

Comment: @seberg -- Precisely.  This will only work in very simple circumstances.  However, I think that it's a common enough simple circumstance to be worth mentioning.

Comment: Yeah, just wanted to warn, especially since there is a change with version 1.7. here. In his case, and if you also throw in strides information, you should be able to get quite far though.

Comment: Unfortunately, as helpful as this is, its doesn't seem to work with matplotlib.cm.get_array() - the base of that array is just the same array, but the looks oft things.

Comment: @nrob - For what you're wanting to do, there are simpler ways. Just write a wrapper class that holds on to the original data and sets the viewed data to a new slice on a button press or slider update.  As a quick example: https://gist.github.com/joferkington/5682690

Comment: Thanks Joe - I think that looks like it might be the most practical idea.